# How to remove fields in a FieldArray that has a field with a class component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

```
<ul className="list-unstyled">
    {fields.map((tier, index) => (
        <li key={index} className={tierClass(index)}>
            <div">
                <h4 className="magento-h5">
                    {editionTitle} ({edition}) Support Tier {index + 1}
                </h4>
                {fields.length > 1 && (
                    <button
                        type="button"
                        title="Remove Tier"
                        onClick={() => fields.remove(index) }>  
                    </button>
                )}
            </div>
            <div">
                <div>
                    <Field
                        name={`${tier}.monthly_period`}
                        id={`${tier}.monthly_period`}
                        component={RFSelect}
                        type="select"
                        label="Renewal Period"
                        options={renewalPeriodSelect}
                    />
                </div>

            </div>
            <Field
                index={`${tier}`}
                name={`${tier}.long_description`}
                type="text"
                component={RFRichTextArea}
            />
        </li>
    ))}        
</ul>
```

`RFRichTextArea` was derived from https://gist.github.com/erikras/5ca8dc618bae5dbc8faf7d2324585d01

`fields.remove(index)` will remove the fields but the field with the `RFRichTextArea` component doesn't re-render. It keeps the value that was supposed to get remove. 
The redux store form value is correct but what is rendered isn't.

For example: If I have 2 field sets in the array.

```
[ [value:'simple A'], //input field function component
    [value:'complex A'] //class component
]
[ [value:'simple B'],
  [value:'complex B']
]
```

and I remove the first index, I get:

```
[ [value:'simple B'], // input field function component
    [value:'complex A'] //class component
]
```

After some more research, I narrowed down issue.
In my rich text component:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) { 
    this.state.value.setContentFromString(nextProps.input.value, "html");
}
```

The state is updated but also preserves the location of caret.
If I change the statement to `this.setState({value: RichTextEditor.createValueFromString(nextProps.input.value, 'html')})`, that would work but then I loose the position of the caret.

Comment: `RFSelect` is a select field,  that is a stateless component which does show the correct value once a child is removed.

Comment: `rerenderOnEveryChange` on the FieldArray doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I found a solution:

Comment: if(!nextProps.meta.active && this.state.value.toString('html') !== 
    nextProps.input.value) {
            this.setState({value: 
    RichTextEditor.createValueFromString(nextProps.input.value, 'html')})
        }
        else {
            this.state.value.setContentFromString(nextProps.input.value, "html");
        }

Answer (score 0):

In my rich text component `RFRichTextArea`:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) { 
    if(!nextProps.meta.active && this.state.value.toString('html') !== nextProps.input.value) {
        this.setState({value: RichTextEditor.createValueFromString(nextProps.input.value, 'html')})
    }
    else {
        this.state.value.setContentFromString(nextProps.input.value, "html");
    }
}
```